# Android open reading only sqlite database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I trying to do an simple android application, this application need to looking in a database.

I just need to read information from the database. I don't need to copy the database, i just want to do some query on it.

I have read through many sites and tutorials and have been unable to understand how i can do it.

I have found a lot of things about how to create a database but just some few things about when you already have a database. And then people want to copy the database, but i don't understand how to do without copying the database. It's not useful for me because i just want to read it and i will not change it.

If someone know a easy way to do that or a tutorial who explain how to do, thanks in advance.

Comment: what you really need ? i'm looking for some code, i tried many different stuff and realize it's not what i looking for, each time i had to copying the database. Now i start over and ask if someone know how to do without copying the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hi,Try This Tutorial,Think Its Useful for beginners](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) 
NB:-Dont download the code first study basics ,it will be nice..

Comment: I have already read this one and it doesn't help me. It's more for create a database and add stuff. I already have my database, i want to read it.

Comment: `Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, 
                null, "id=? AND task_id=?", new String{value1, value2}, null, null);`

Comment: Before to do a query on it i need to open it. The name of my database is test.db but i don't no if i need an database handler or if i can just use a method who open the db ?

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` this is used to open a db

Comment: there is must be something before where i said "the database you have to read is /*name of my database*/ ". something like SQLiteDatabase db = open(name.db) and after i have to do db.getWritableDatabase(); no ?

Comment: i accept these answer because there is some stuff in these tutorial who can help me but not enough

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to copy database from your assets to your emulator or in device,but if you check your asset file it will not change because its already copied in your device or emulator,if you want to do uninstall your app and want to run it again then you have no fear that your database will change or its value thats why copy the database.

Comment: But i if i copying a database with a size of 2Mo it will take 4Mo ...
And this is no way to access to a database without copying it ?

Comment: Because some applications are local apps they are not connected with server if you edit its database then or if you want to clear data from your device  or emulator then it will totally change and how will you get it again so in android we makes its copy or you can say its backup.
now i think so its much clear to you.
Thanks

Comment: It's was already clear but i think i don't explain correctly. My "boss" want for some reason, not only these, he don't want to copying the database. I have to only open in readable only. I know it isn't the best way to do but he said it will be better like that. So i had to start over.